# this operation requires iis integrated pipeline mode

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have ajax call on my aspx page as:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "/SiteAdmin3/UpsIntegration.aspx/addUpdatePackageData",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        '_OrderNumber': $("#txtOrderNumber").val(),
                        '_PackageNumber': $("#lblPackageNumber").html(),
                        '_Height': $("#txtPackageHeight").val(),
                        '_Width': $("#txtPackageWidth").val(),
                        '_Lenght': $("#txtPackageLenght").val(),
                        '_Weight': $("#txtPackageWeight").val(),
                        '_ReferanceNumber1': $("#txtPackageReferanceNumber1").val(),
                        '_ReferanceNumber2': $("#txtPackageReferanceNumber2").val(),
                        '_ReferanceNumber3': $("#txtPackageReferanceNumber3").val(),
                        '_ReferanceNumber4': $("#txtPackageReferanceNumber4").val(),
                        '_ReferanceNumber5': $("#txtPackageReferanceNumber5").val(),
                        '_PackageType': $("#ddlAddPackageType").val()
                    }),
                    contentType: 'application/json;',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (Data) {

//whatever operation to be performed
},
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert("Error in Saving.Please try later." + JSON.stringify(err));
                    }
                });
```

On cs page my addUpdatePackageData method is:

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static ShipStationIntegration[] addUpdatePackageData(string _OrderNumber, string _PackageNumber, string _Height, string _Width, string _Lenght, string _Weight, string _ReferanceNumber1, string _ReferanceNumber2, string _ReferanceNumber3, string _ReferanceNumber4, string _ReferanceNumber5, string _PackageType)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<ShipStationIntegration> lst = new List<ShipStationIntegration>();
        try
        {
            lst = bindPackageListFromPageMethod();



            return lst.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return lst.ToArray();
        }

    }
```

This returns correct list.

Butafter getting responce it always goes in error block of ajax as and gives error as:

[image]

I am not understanding what is wrong in it?

I also tried with:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

But still error was there.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you running this through IIS? Is yes, what is `Managed Pipeline Mode`  set to?

Comment: @scheien no i am not running this through IIS

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the VS 2010 integrated web server (Cassini), it does not support Integrated Pipeline mode. You'll need to download IIS Express and set your project to use it instead.

Comment: but cant i get simple toArray() responce in Json??

Comment: Anytime you are modifing the data returned in a response integrated pipeline mode is required.

Answer (score 1):

When your return from a webmethod and the response format should be `JSON` the response pass to a `httpModule` that serialize the response into `JSON` and try to execute `Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");` BUT this way to add http headers are not supported by Cassini because this way needs Integrated Pipeline mode and as @Kevin says:

> Cassini does not support Integrated Pipeline